# GraphAPI Channel creation results in hidden channels

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

we're currently running into some side effects in regards to recent changes on the GraphAPI/Teams channel creation.

On our tenant channel creation via GraphAPI now results in channels being listed as hidden.

One of our customer doesn't even see them at all.

The only thing mentioned in recent changelogs is the new membershipType, aka private channels (which for us doesn't work at all right now, but that's another story).

We didn't change any logic in our application and even the simple example in the Graph Explorer results in hidden channels.

Is there any known workaround for this behaviour other than unhiding them by hand? Any new parameter perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

*For reference the Graph Explorer example code:*

```
Endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels

{
  "displayName": "Architecture Discussion",
  "description": "This channel is where we debate all future architecture plans"
}
```

Comment: I'm still having this issue today, it looks like this is not a priority for Microsoft.